# Get first element from a dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-3.5

I have the following declaration:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> like = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

I need to get the first element out, but do not know the key or value. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Define "first" for a dictionary.

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered.

Comment: Related (none other than Skeet):  http://stackoverflow.com/q/436954/1001985

Comment: Using First() makes sense when you know there is only one item in the dictionary because you have done a .Count on the dictionary. Then you don't need to do a foreach loop on one item, just use First()

Comment: @LouiseEggleton This is exactly how I am using this solution. Thanks for being level headed about OP's question.

Comment: Could also use Single() or SingleOrDefault() instead of First(), if you know that it only has one item.

Comment: @AustinSalonen "as the first element returned in a for each statement"

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Note that to call `First` here is actually to call a Linq extension of IEnumerable, which is implemented by `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`.  But for a Dictionary, "first" doesn't have a defined meaning.  According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/436954/1001985), the last item added ends up being the "First" (in other words, it behaves like a *Stack*), but that is implementation specific, it's not the *guaranteed* behavior.  In other words, to *assume* you're going to get any defined item by calling *First* would be to beg for trouble -- using it should be treated as akin to getting a *random* item from the Dictionary, as noted by Bobson below.  However, sometimes this is useful, as you just need *any* item from the Dictionary.

---

Just use the Linq `First()`:

```
var first = like.First();
string key = first.Key;
Dictionary<string,string> val = first.Value;
```

Note that using `First` on a dictionary gives you a `KeyValuePair`, in this case `KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string,string>>`.

---

Note also that you *could* derive a specific meaning from the use of `First` by combining it with the Linq `OrderBy`:

```
var first = like.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key).First();
```

Comment: I've suggested an edit to change `val` to its proper value (since it's a string) but I guess it was rejected?

Comment: @Eve - Yes, because val is a `Dictionary<string, string>`, and `like` is a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>`.

Comment: Oh, my bad, sorry for the distraction.

Comment: @dbaseman A dictionary doesn't have a first pair.  Just because you called `First` on a `Dictionary` doesn't mean that you actually got the first item in the dictionary.  You got *an* item in the dictionary, but not the first item.  There is no first item, because dictionaries are unordered.  This type of answer only further harms the OP because they will continue to believe that they are actually getting the "first" item, even though no such thing exists.  The proper answer to the question is that there is no first item.

Comment: @Servy - There is exactly one scenario I can think of where calling `First` on a dictionary is worth doing: When you want to access a property of the key or value objects which should be the same on all of them (i.e. a backreference to the parent in a dictionary of children).

Comment: @Bobson I can think of others still.  The point is that you need to realize it's not "the first item" it's "an arbitrary item".  As long as you're clear what it's doing, and are okay with that, then it's fine.  The OP specifically said he wanted "the first item".  No such thing exists.  If he asked for "an arbitrary item" then this answer would be 100% correct.

Comment: I get the error `Type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<K,V>

Comment: @Bobson it is meaningful. I have a dictionary of department (string) and department code (string). Someone in my company could work for just one department or be considered in a few. I check the count of the dictionary entries, and if there is only one then I would like that department without knowing the key or value of it. If they have more than one then I make the choose one and send that one back instead.

Comment: Thanks, my use case for this is implementing a DBObj.SelectFirst() method (a select method that just returns the first column of the first row of results). The nature of my method allows for me to pass that undefined behavior on to the calling function if they decide to use a query which produces more items than it should in the first place. In this case, I could use .first(), .last(), .rnd()....it doesn't matter. In practice, it always (so far) returns exactly what you wanted anyway in this case because Dictionary objects tend to keep the order they were created in.

Comment: For others saying we're not really getting the first one - if you use `.OrderBy` and order it so the one you want is on top, yes, you are getting the first one.  And if you just have a dictionary of one item, Iike I was doing, you are also getting the first one.

Comment: You may want to just pull any value from the collection, which is what you really are doing here. You shouldn't think of dictionaries in terms of "first" but there are still reasons you might want to just pull ONE value like i said here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820506/get-first-key-from-dictionarystring-string

Answer (score 32):

For anyone coming to this that wants a linq-less way to get **an** element from a dictionary

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
d.Add("a", "b");
var e = d.GetEnumerator();
e.MoveNext();
var anElement = e.Current;
// anElement/e.Current is a KeyValuePair<string,string>
// where Key = "a", Value = "b"
```

I'm not sure if this is implementation specific, but if your Dictionary doesn't have any elements, `Current` will contain a `KeyValuePair<string, string>` where both the key and value are `null`.

(I looked at the logic behind linq's `First` method to come up with this, and tested it via `LinqPad 4`)

Comment: Enumerators are `IDisposable` objects, so you should use `using` construct here.

Answer (score 16):

Though you can use `First()`, Dictionaries do not have order per se. Please use [OrderedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) instead. And then you can do `FirstOrDefault`. This way it will be meaningful.

Comment: I don't know about "safe".  "Meaningful" would be more appropriate.  First will do *something* for a `Dictionary`, you just have no idea what that something is, unlike an ordered dictionary in which case `First` has a meaningful value.

Comment: +1, but just a thought: Not good for performance, as OrderedDictionary is non-generic, which means boxing / unboxing has to take place.

Answer (score 5):

EDIT: 
Use an OrderedDictionary.

It's better to use `FirstOrDefault()` to retrieve the first value.

Ex:

```
var firstElement = like.FirstOrDefault();
string firstElementKey = firstElement.Key;
Dictinary<string,string> firstElementValue = firstElement.Value;
```

Comment: The advantage of `FirstOrDefault()` is that it will give a default value if there is none present in the dictionary.

Comment: And yet since a Dictionary is unordered, there is no such thing as a "first" item in a dictionary in the first place.  No such item exists.  You can get *an* item from the dictionary, but you need to have an ordered data structure to get the "first".

Comment: I agree. Having an `orderedDictionary` makes sense for "First".

Answer (score 3):

```
using System.Linq;

Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> like = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
Dictionary<string, string> first = like.Values.First();
```

Comment: .Values.First() doesn't exist... are you using System.Collection.Generic?

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't exists'? Remember that First() is an extension method, so you must include `using System.Linq` in your using directives

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary does not define order of items. If you just need an item use `Keys` or `Values` properties of dictionary to pick one.

Answer (score 1):

ill find easy way to find first element in Dictionary :)

```
 Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> like = 
 newDictionary<string,Dictionary<string, string>>();

 foreach(KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, string>> _element in like)
 {
   Console.WriteLine(_element.Key); // or do something
   break;
 }
```

Comment: exactly; I hoped there were a cleaner syntax for this solution but I didn't found

Answer (score 0):

convert to Array

```
var array = like.ToArray();
var first = array[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way of to index a Collection in terms of performance, high compatibility (2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1, 4.6.2, 4.7, 4.7.1, 4.7.2, 4.8) and easy implemention.

Save today!!
Its not only a items copy, this is items reference of a Collection!!
buy it!!

```
string [] arrayString = new string[like.Count];
like.Values.CopyTo( arrayString,0 );

arrayString[0] //First
```

References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1.copyto?view=net-5.0

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dc5e4242-64d3-45ac-bdea-cf4f3d9abdbb/icollectioncopyto-vs-arraylisttoarray?forum=netfxbcl

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.