# How to retrieve first row from dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to retrieve first row from this dictionary. I put around some 15 records.

```
Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>> headINFO = 
                                   new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, string>> { };
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: get first key from Dictionary<string, string>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820506/c-get-first-key-from-dictionarystring-string)

Comment: If you want the first element from a dictionary, you are probably using the wrong tool. The fact that you are calling it a row underscores it.

Comment: I mean first record... sorry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get first element from a dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979966/get-first-element-from-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 7):

You can use [headINFO.First()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx), but unless you know that there always will be at least one entry in `headINFO` I would recommend that you use [headINFO.FirstOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx).

More information on the differences between the two available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024559/when-to-use-first-and-when-to-use-firstordefault-with-linq).

**Edit:** *Added simple examples*

Here is a quick example on how to use `FirstOrDefault()`

```
var info = headINFO.FirstOrDefault().Value;
Console.WriteLine(info.Item1); // Prints Tuple item1
Console.WriteLine(info.Item2); // Prints Tuple item2
```

If you want to print multiple items you can use [Take(x)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx). In this case we will loop through three dictionary items, but you can easily modify the number to grab more items.

```
foreach (var info in headINFO.Take(3))
{
    Console.WriteLine(info.Value.Item1);
    Console.WriteLine(info.Value.Item2);
}
```

You should also keep in mind that the above `foreach` does not allow you to modify the values of your `Dictionary` entries directly.

**Edit2:** *Clarified usage of First() and added clean foreach example*

Keep in mind that while `First()` and `FirstOrDefault()` will provide you with a single item it does in no way guarantee that it will be the first item added.

Also, if you simply want to loop through all the items you can remove the `Take(3)` in the foreach loop mentioned above.

```
foreach (var info in headINFO)
{
    Console.WriteLine(info.Key);          // Print Dictionary Key
    Console.WriteLine(info.Value.Item1);  // Prints Turple Value 1
    Console.WriteLine(info.Value.Item2);  // Prints Turple Value 2
}
```

Comment: I have some 15 rows in the dictionary. from that I just want to retrieve each row separately and assign it to different local variables... eg) 1st String ID, 2nd String Head, 3rd STRING Content... SO now first row i want to assign it to these three varaiables... same way for second row and so on...

Answer (score 5):

Dictionaries are unordered, so there is no way to retrieve the first key-value pair you inserted.

You can retrieve **an** item by calling the LINQ `.First()` method.

Comment: Hmm... I always use FirstOrDefault(), but I don't think it'd be a huge difference

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is just to use Linq's [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx) extension method:

```
var firstHead = headINFO.First();
```

Or if you want to be safer, the [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) method will return `null` if the dictionary is empty:

```
var firstHead = headINFO.FirstOrDefault();
```

If you'd like to loop through all items in the dictionary, try this:

```
foreach(var head in headINFO)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: @vimal you can do `.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()`, but it sounds like you're going about this the wrong way. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have some 15 rows in the dictionary. from that I just want to retrieve each row separately and assign it to different local variables... eg) 1st String ID, 2nd String Head, 3rd STRING Content... SO now first row i want to assign it to these three varaiables... same way for second row and so on...

Comment: whatever you are trying to do, but doesn't sound something good.

Comment: @vimal you probably want to use a `foreach` loop, or better yet, you may want to rethink using a dictionary at all -- whatever you're doing, there's probably a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.

```
headINFO.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    int c=0;

    foreach(var item in myDictionary)
    {
         c++;
         if(c==1)
         {
             myFirstVar = item.Value;
         }
         else if(c==2)
         {
             mySecondVar = item.Value;
         }
          ......
    }
```